# Not able to connect to internet in ubuntu after changing modem settings

Tags: networking, ubuntu, internet

I used to connect from broadband connection in ubuntu as shown in

https://askubuntu.com/questions/100489/how-to-set-up-a-broadband-connection

but then I did some changes in modem as shown in

http://www.ashout.com/error-651-with-pppoe-connections-in-windows-7-fix/

after that  I am not able to connect despite making changes.Although in windows it works fine since am able to connect to internet without making connection.

I also tried the changes mentioned in the given link but it did not help much

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/ubuntu-networking-configuration-using-command-line.html

when typing `sudo ifconfig`

[image]

and when I opened and changed gksudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces and restarted the networking,yet it did not connect!

[image]

please help!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried resetting your Modem. Perhaps the most basic things should be checked first.

Comment: yes I have,both mechanically and with command `sudo usb_modeswitch -R -v`